# React/Next.js doesn't seem to work with Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, apexcharts

### Problem

My Next.js/React/Node app crashes when I `import Chart from "react-apexcharts"` in any file. Attempting to visit the app results in the following error: 
`Server Error`
`ReferenceError: window is not defined`
`This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.`
 (see call stack below).
 This happens regardless if the imported `<Chart/>` is rendered in the page or just left unused. Interesting thing is, if I save a file and initiate a Next.js quick refresh, my app begins working as normal (sometimes). But, when I just launch the app and attempt to visit it, or when I manually refresh with **f5**, the aforementioned error occurs. Basically, it only works after a Next.js quick refresh (and sometimes, presumably randomly, it doesn't work in this scenario either, throwing the same error as before).

### Environment

Node.js (14.16.0), React (17.0.2), Express (4.17.1), Next.js (10.2.0), `react-apexcharts` (1.3.9), `apexcharts` (3.26.3), Edge Browser, Win10.
Next.js server is integrated together with Express server.

### Logging

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\georg\Documents\development\web\projects\Angelina-Website\node_modules\apexcharts\dist\apexcharts.common.js:6:345884)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)     
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\georg\Documents\development\web\projects\Angelina-Website\node_modules\react-apexcharts\dist\react-apexcharts.min.js:1:722)      
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)   
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)        
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)     
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.react-apexcharts (C:\Users\georg\Documents\development\web\projects\Angelina-Website\.next\server\pages\partner\dashboard.js:4973:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\georg\Documents\development\web\projects\Angelina-Website\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The above issue appears because you created the next.js app with SSR enabled

To solve this issue, you need to import the `apex-charts` component dynamically with SSR disabled.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
    
const Chart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });
```

Answer (score 23):

You should import it using this :

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('yourcomponent using react apex-charts'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

because of the use of window it's not working with the ssr mode enabled

Comment: I had marked my component as no ssr, but still got the error. @xorozo's answer works perfectly, use that.